# Using hadoop for data analytics

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hive, analytics

I have a question regarding implementation of hadoop in one of my projects. Basically the requirement is that, we receive buch of logs on daily basis containing information regarding videos(When it was played, when it stopped, which user playe it etc).

What we have to do is analyze these files and return stats data in response to an HTTP request.
Example request: http://somesite/requestData?startDate=someDate&endDate=anotherDate. Basically this request asks for count of all videos played between a date Range.

My question is can we use hadoop to solve this?

I have read in various articles hadoop is not real time. So to approach this scenario should i use hadoop in conjunction with MySQL?

**What i have thought of doing is to write a Map/Reduce job and store count for each video for each day in mysql.** The hadoop job can be scheduled to run like once a day. Mysql data can then be used to serve the request in real time.

Is this approach correct? Is hive useful in this in any way? Please provide some guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is correct - you can create the per day data with MR job or Hive and store them in MySQL for serving in real time.

However newer versions of Hive when configured with Tez can provide decent query performance. You could try storing your per day data in Hive serve them directly from there. If the query is a simple select, it should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding using Hadoop is an investment, as you'll need clusters and development/operational effort.

For a Hadoop solution to make sense, your data must be *big*. Big, as in terabytes of data, coming in real fast, possibly without proper catalog information. If you can store/process your data in your current environment, run your analysis there.

Assuming your aim is not educational, I strongly recommend you to reconsider your choice of Hadoop. Unless you have real big data, it'll only cost you more effort.

On the other hand, if you really need a distributed solution, I think your approach of daily runs is correct, accept that there are better alternatives to writing a Map/Reduce job, such as Hive, Pig or Spark.